# How to "offline" access PDBs for post-mortem managed exception analysis

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone provide some sample code how to make a post-mortem lookup into the PDBs of a managed application on a symbol server to retrieve source file/line number for a managed stack trace containing the following stack frame information:

```
<StackFrame  
  module = "TestBench.exe"  
  className = "TestBench.Program"  
  methodName = "Main"  
  methodSignature = "Void Main(System.String[])"  
  methodToken = "0x6000001"  
  ILOffset = "49"  
  NativeOffset = "212"/>
```

The idea is to get full source information without deploying PDBs to the field (see http://timstall.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/getting_file_and_line_numbers_without_deploying_the_pdb_file.htm)

The main question is how to get a symbol reader for a specific version of a managed module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a symbol server much like Microsoft provide for the .Net framework. This will hook into your source control system to ensure you can step into the file/line

this is the best link i have found

[Setting Up a Symbol Server](http://entland.homelinux.com/blog/2006/07/06/setting-up-a-symbol-server/)

We are looking at setting up something similar at the moment too.

I think you will still need to deploy your PDB's though